# Convert differences between SQL Server 2008 R2 and 2012

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I've got an issue while executing a SQL statement in SQL Server 2012 while it's perfectly working in a SQL Server 2008 R2...

The error message is :

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
>   Error converting data type varchar
>   to numeric.

I want  to execute this SQL Select statement :

```
Select 
    count(*)
from IMPORTBM 
    inner join ATTRIBUTE on ATT_ATTRIBUTE_ID = IMP_ATTRIBUTE_ID 
where IMP_LOCATION_ID = 2 
    AND IMP_SERIAL_ID = 310001 
    AND IMP_VERSION_ID = 1 
    AND (
        (ATT_ATTRIBUTE = 'PS_APISizing' 
            AND IMP_VALUE = 'C')
        OR
        (ATT_ATTRIBUTE = 'DTD' 
            AND ISNUMERIC(IMP_VALUE) = 1  
            AND  CAST( IMP_VALUE  as NUMERIC(38,19)) <= 0.469) 
        OR
        (ATT_ATTRIBUTE = 'IOD' 
        AND ISNUMERIC(IMP_VALUE) = 1  
        AND  CAST( IMP_VALUE  as NUMERIC(38,19)) BETWEEN 3.684 AND 4.225) 
    )
```

Could you help me finding out why it's not working with SQL Server 2012 please ?

Comment: Note that if I remove one of the two `where` clause having `ISNUMERIC` function, the sql statement works.

Comment: This is one of the dangers of using Entity-Attribute-Value schemes...

Comment: @ErikE I did not have other choice but to use this solution... :( we talk here about the configuration of an oil pump.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that conditions are not always evaluated in the order you place them. This means that `Cast(IMP_VALUE as numeric(38, 19))` can fail when it is a non-numeric value, if the query execution plan happens to evaluate this before the `IsNumeric(IMP_VALUE) = 1`.

This is not determined by how many clauses there are or what version of SQL Server you're running--those are only coincidences. The problem is exactly as I described. The fact that you get different results with different queries is due to different queries, or different servers, using different execution plans.

The cure is to make sure that all conditions will not throw an error, no matter what order they are executed in.

For all versions of SQL Server, you can do this:

```
Convert(
   numeric(38,19),
   CASE WHEN IsNumeric(IMP_VALUE) = 1 THEN IMP_VALUE ELSE NULL END
) <= 0.469
```

Or, in SQL Server 2012 and up, you can use [Try_Convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993(v=sql.110).aspx):

```
Try_Convert(numeric(38,19), IMP_VALUE) <= 0.469
```

If your server complains that this is not a built-in function name, then it is likely that your database was upgraded from a prior version and you need to [alter the database compatibility level](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx). Note that doing this could have some other effects in the system that you need to consider, so study up on it first, and try it out in a non-production system before doing it in production (or do it during a non-critical period and set the compatibility level back if you run into any issues). The danger is not that any damage will occur, but that query results could be different or errors could occur (different ordering of query or stored procedure results being a more common occurrence).

```
ALTER DATABASE database_name 
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 110; -- SQL Server 2012
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.  I tried the `CASE ... END` solution you gave me, and I have an error : `Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.` . For the compatibility level, my db is  replicated from a SQL Server 2008 R2 db with transactionnal replication. So I don't think I can upgrade the compatibility level easily :S ...

Comment: My apologies, I left out a `Convert` or `Cast`. Please try again with the updated answer.

Comment: Or you can wrap the entire expression in a Cast or Convert as I did.

Comment: Yes I tried this too and I think it's more clear like that :) thanks @ErikE !

Answer (score 1):

What is the definition of the table? (IMP_VALUE at least). Why not store numeric in the 1st place...
2008 and 2012 query plan probably differ and does not handle the parameter and condition in the same order.

With SQL Server 2012 (compatibility level 110) you can try to replace the 2 cast:

```
 AND ISNUMERIC(IMP_VALUE) = 1  
        AND  CAST( IMP_VALUE  as NUMERIC(38,19)) <= 0.469)
```

by

```
AND TRY_CONVERT(NUMERIC(38,19), IMP_VALUE) <= 0.469
AND  TRY_CONVERT(NUMERIC(38,19), IMP_VALUE) BETWEEN 3.684 AND 4.225
```

It returns NULL without error when it cannot convert it.

Comment: thanks for your answer @Julien Vavasseur.   IMP_Value is a varchar(100) field. IMP_Value can be numeric or varchar value. I tried the TRY_CONVERT but I've got the error : "Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 13
`TRY_CONVERT' is not a recognized built-in function name.`

Comment: do not forget that it works if only one where clause with `ISNUMERIC` function is specified.

Comment: you can only use try convert with SQL Server 2012 and its compatibiliy level (110). with 2008 use case when isnumeric() then cast(imp_value as umeric) else null end

Comment: `and isnumeric() and other condition` does not guarantee evaluation order either. For code that is compatible with both versions, much safer to say `CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC() = 1 THEN CAST(...) END <= 0.469`